# Logic Problem about Complex Subjects and Predicates

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

**Write down the English sentences that correspond to the following formulas.**

[image]

Mx: x is a moose.

Ex: x is an elk.

Wx: x lives in the woods.

Fx: x fears humans.

Tx: x is threatened.

Yx: x has young.

Rx: x runs.

**Please tell me if my answer is correct.** Not all mooses or elks that live in the woods and do not fear humans run, if they are threatened or have young.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's correct ... and I don't think you can say it in a way that's more natural or easier to comprehend.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!

Comment: Sure. Looking at it again, maybe one small improvement might be to say 'will run' instead of just run, otherwise one could take it to be that the running is about the humans (and that the moose and elks do not fear humans running!)

Comment: Very interesting perspective!